# String unique characters

Tags: string

Implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters. What if you can not use additional data structures?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Pls tag homework questions as homework

Comment: @brian it is not a homework it is one of techincal questions on the website

@michael it is just any string like say"abcedef"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can use a little auxiliary memory, then a small array of bits (indexed by the numerical code of the character) is all you need (if your characters are 4-byte Unicode ones you'll probably want a hashmap instead;-).  Start with all bits at 0: scan the string from the start -- each time, you've found a duplicate if the bit corresponding to the current character is already 1 -- otherwise, no duplicates yet, set that bit to 1.  This is O(N).

If you can't allocate any extra memory, but can alter the string, sorting the string then doing a pass to check for adjacent duplicates is the best you can do, O(N log N).

If you can't allocate extra memory and cannot alter the string, you need an O(N squared) check where each character is checked vs all the following ones.

Answer (score 2):

we can do it by assigning a prime number to every character.. and multiply it for every character found. then on every character check that if the value is divisible by the number assigned to that character or not..

Answer (score 2):

answer in c program

```
int is_uniq(char *str) 
{
    int i = 0, flag = 0, value = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        value = str[i] - 'a';
        if(flag & (1 << value)) {
            return 0;
        }
        flag |= (1 << value);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: what about string like "AbcdDEfh". what is significant of using str[i]-'a'?

Answer (score 1):

```
for each character in the string
  if any subsequent character matches it
    fail
succeed
```

Comment: i think we need to sort the string for that which is not a very efficient solution

Comment: Why would you need to sort it for that?

Comment: oh u meant compare each character with the all the others characters of the string but that would result in a O(n*n) complexity

Comment: Yes, the complexity is high, but I can't think of a more efficient way to do it with no data structures, and a negative vote doesn't help my brain.  If you wanted a more efficient algorithm, it would have been nice to have asked in your question.

Comment: This would work well as a recursive algorithm.  Bonus: some people may not consider using the stack as an "additional data structure," although I think they'd be wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution - You could extract the string into an array of characters, sort the array, and then loop over it, checking to see if the next character is equal to the current one.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;

public class uniqueChar
{
    boolean checkUniqueChar(String strin)
    {
        int m;
        char []str=strin.toCharArray();
        java.util.Arrays.sort(str);
        for(int i=0;i<str.length-1;i++)
        {
            if(str[i]==str[i+1])
                 return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void  main(String argv[]) throws IOException 
    {
        String str;
        System.out.println("enter the string\n");
        InputStreamReader in=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader bin=new BufferedReader(in);
        str=bin.readLine();
        System.out.println(new uniqueChar().checkUniqueChar(str));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the prime method described by partik (based on this [theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)). It's O(N).

```
# one prime per letter
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101]

starting_byte = ?a.ord
primes_product = 1

ARGV[0].each_byte do |byte|
    current_prime = primes[byte - starting_byte]
    if primes_product % current_prime == 0
        puts "Not unique"
        exit 
    else
        primes_product = primes_product * current_prime
    end
end

puts "Unique"
```

Answer (score 0):

I came on this thread for the similar question and ended up with the following solution in C#:

```
        var data = "ABCDEFGADFGHETFASAJUTE";

        var hash = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        foreach (char c in data)
        {
            if (hash.ContainsKey(c))
            {
                hash[c] += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                hash.Add(c, 1);
            }
        }

        var Characters = hash.Keys.ToArray();
        var Frequencies = hash.Values.ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
    int checker = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
        if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0)
            return false;
        checker |= (1 << val);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should comment on your code.

Comment: Can you explain your solution?

Comment: On what ground did you decide that an integer can cover all unicode chars or even ASCII characters ? The assumption that  string has only lowercase alphabet letter is not correct