# Determine whether a UTF-32 encoded string has unique characters

Tags: java, string, bitvector, utf-32

I have a question about using the bit-vector approach that is common to finding whether a string has unique characters. I have seen those solutions out there ([one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057827/determining-a-string-has-all-unique-characters-without-using-additional-data-str)) work well for ASCII and UTF-16 character set.

However, how will the same approach work for UTF-32? The longest continuous bit vector can be a long variable in Java right? UTF-16 requires 1024 such variables. If we take the same approach it will require 2^26 long variables (I think). Is it possible to solve for such a big character set using bit-vector?

Comment: This question is very open ended; some code with a specific question would be better.  I also disagree that utf-16 and utf-32 require different number of descriptors/vectors to fully describe the utf character set.

Comment: Within the context of your question, are these distinct: `a`, `a` followed by the Unicode combining "character" diaeresis, or `a` with a diaeresis ("aää", that's four codepoints)?

Comment: @TomBlodget Yes sort of. I am not too sure about what you mean by codepoints, but I am actually imagining this problem as comparing numerical byte value. So `a` and `ä`are not equal per se.

Comment: A codepoint is an element of the "character" set; a number which may or may not have a "character" associated with it. Unicode has some codepoints termed "combining characters". A non-combining codepoint can be followed by any number of combining codepoints. Together, they form a grapheme. Unfortunately, Unicode has multiple representations of the same graphemes: "ä" vs "ä". Through normalization, you can convert "ä" (U+00E4) into "ä" (U+0061 U+0308) but then you'd have to account for that when comparing with "a" (U+0061).

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing something important here.  UTF-32 is an encoding for Unicode.  Unicode actually fits within a 21 bit space.  As the [Unicode FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#gen0) states:

> *"The Unicode Standard encodes characters in the range U+0000..U+10FFFF, which amounts to a 21-bit code space."*

Any UTF-32 "characters" that are outside of the Unicode code space are invalid ... and you should *never* see them in a UTF-32 encoded `String`.  So 2^15 longs should be enough.

In practice, you are unlikely to see code points outside of the Basic Linguistic Plane (plane 0).  So it makes sense to use a bitmap for the BMP (i.e. codes up to 65535) and a sparse data structure (e.g. a `HashSet<Integer>`) for the other panes.

You could also consider using [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) instead for "rolling your own" bit-set data structures using `long` or `long[]`.

---

Finally, I should not that some of the code in the Q&A that you linked to is NOT appropriate for looking for unique characters in UTF-16 for a couple of reasons:

- The idea of using N variables of type `long` and a switch statement *does not scale*.  The code of the switch statement gets large and unmanageable ... and possibly gets bigger than the JVM spec can cope with.  (The maximum size of a compiled method is 2^16 - 1 bytes of bytecode, so it clearly isn't viable for implementing a bit-vector for all of the Unicode code space.)

  It is a better idea to use an array of `long` and get rid of the need for a `switch` ... which is only really there because you have N distinct `long` variables.
- In UTF-16, each code unit (16 bit value) encodes either 1 code point (character) or half a code point.  If you simply create a bitmap of the code units, you won't detect unique characters properly.

Comment: Agreed. The [W3](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/definitions-characters/#unicode) page describes Unicode as set encompassing all current and even ancient language characters. So I think many characters are likely than 65535. But I like your idea of bitmap for BMP and HashSet for others.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a `long` contains 64 bits of information, and the set of UTF-32 characters contains approximately 2^21 elements, which would require 2^21 bits of information. You would be right that it would require 2^26 long variables if the UTF-32 dataset used all bits. However, as it is, you only require 2^13 `long` variables (still a lot).

If you assume that the characters are evenly distributed over the dataset, this inefficiency is unavoidable and the best solution would be to use something else like a `Set<Long>` or something. However, English plaintext tends to have a majority of its characters in the ASCII range (0-127), and most Western languages are fairly constrained to a specific range, so you could use a bit vector for the high-frequency regions and a `Set` or other order-independent, high-efficiency `contains` data structure to represent the rest of the regions.

Comment: The number space of Unicode codepoints is 0x0 to 0x10FFFF, less than 2^21.